# How to check the similarity score between two web urls?

Tags: web-scraping, url, similarity, sentence-similarity

I'm working on a project that frequently needs to check the similarity score between two web url, initially i did this by scraping all the text from the web page and then calculated the document similarity. However this is really time consuming, instead what i'm looking for is a way which can detect the similarity between urls by just using the contents of the url instead of going through all the text.

```
eg:
url1:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe
url2:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess
a rough similarity estimate : 67% (since both are from wiki and both are related to games)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably better off comparing individual pieces of URL as foo.com/a/b/c and boo.com/a/b/c would have similar sequence score but would probably have very different contents.

For this you can use:

- Python's `urllib.parse.urlparse()` to separate urls into different parts like netloc (domain), path and parameters
- Python's `difflib.SequenceMatcher` which can tell how similar two strings are.
- `w3lib.url.canonicalize_url` to normalize your urls as different order of parameters etc result in the same content though look very different. See [w3lib docs](https://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more.

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from w3lib.url import canonicalize_url
from urllib.parse import urlparse


def compare_urls(url1, url2):
    url1 = canonicalize_url(url1)
    url2 = canonicalize_url(url2)
    url1_parsed = urlparse(url1)
    url2_parsed = urlparse(url2)
    domain = SequenceMatcher(None, url1_parsed.netloc, url2_parsed.netloc).ratio()
    path = SequenceMatcher(None, url1_parsed.path, url2_parsed.path).ratio()
    query = SequenceMatcher(None, url1_parsed.query, url2_parsed.query).ratio()
    return {
        "domain": domain,
        "path": path,
        "query": query,
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(compare_urls(
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess"
    ))
# prints: {'domain': 1.0, 'path': 0.5, 'query': 1.0}
```

By separating sequence comparison to netloc (domain), path and parameters you can assign scores weights to each one of them to design a more successful comparison algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing it in your database I'd defo recommend the Levenshtein distance function.

For example, to use it with postgres:

To install:
`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;`

To search:

```
SELECT 
    url,
    LEVENSHTEIN(url, %s) AS similarity
FROM 
    url_table
ORDER BY 
    similarity;
```